# Nodejs: Efficiently Serving Static Files

Tags: node.js

I'm currently working on a vanilla nodejs server and I am wondering whether there is a better way to serve files (client side files are in a different directory from the server). Right now, in my router file, I am using fs.readFilesSync to load all the needed files and then I'm serving them like this:

```
switch (path) {
    case '/':
      renderHTML(index, res);
      break;
    case '/home':
      renderHTML(index, res);
      break;
    case '/static/js/index/index.js':
      serveJS(indexJS, res);
      break;
    case '/static/css/style.css':
      serveCSS(styleCSS, res);
      break;
    case '/static/js/socket.io-client.js':
      serveJS(socketJS, res);
      break;
    case '/static/js/IOClient.js':
      serveJS(IOClientJS, res);
      break;
```

My directory looks similar to this:

```
\project
    \client
        \css
        \js
        index.html
    \server
        app.js
        router.js
```

Is this the correct way to serve files, or is there a more efficient way? Thank you.

Comment: Is this correct and efficient? Sure. Is this easy to maintain and extend? Hell no. BTW Why don't you leave the task of serving statics to a dedicated server, e.g. nginx?

Comment: Well, there are lots of things that can be done more efficiently than this and they are all implemented in tools already built for serving static files such as `express.static` or `serve-static` or `nginx`, etc...  Things you could implement that these do: cache files, use etag, etc...  Go look at the code for these to see how they do it or use one of them.  And, a table of routes/files is simpler to maintain than a switch statement.